# MUL instruction "Invalid combination of opcode and operands" x86 NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have been working with x86 Assembly

The current state of this loop I wrote to do powers is:

`edi`: temp result
`esi`: exponent
`edx`: original number

```
mov esi, [y]
mov edi, [x]
mov edx, [x]
.powloop:
    mul edi, edx
    sub esi, 1
    cmp esi, 0
    jnz .powloop
    ret
```

When I assemble I get this error:

```
main.asm:22: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

`22` being the line that `mul edi, edx` occurs on.

What am I doing wrong and what are the means to fix this?

Comment: If you ever encounter such an error, consult the instruction set reference about what operands are valid.

Answer (score 1):

The `mul` instruction does not use two operands.
The `mul` instruction mandatory uses the `EAX` register and one other operand.

You can load the original number in `EAX`.

```
; x^y
  mov eax, [x]
  mov esi, [y]
  dec esi
  jz  Done
More:
  mul [x]
  dec esi
  jnz More
Done:
```

Comment: One-operand `mul` is slower than `imul edi, edx` on most CPUs, and imul allows an arbitrary choice of register allocation.  Reloading the memory source operand every iteration probably doesn't hurt in practice.  It might save front-end uops if it micro-fuses, but not back-end uops.  It's also actually larger code-size to use a direct addressing mode than to just `mov eax, edx` or whatever before the loop.